# How to create a dynamic formula to find the average of a set of values for a given vector

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a formula that gives me the average of the last 12 entries in a given dataset depending on the associated vector.

Let's make an example:

I have in column F2,G2,H2 and I2 dates, Company1, Company2 and Company3 respectively. Then from row3 to row 33 I have months dates starting from May 2016.

```
Date    Company1          Company2       Company3
May-16                   2,453,845  
Jun-16                   13,099,823     
Jul-16                   14,159,037     
Aug-16   38,589,050      8,866,101  
Sep-16   63,290,285      13,242,522     
Oct-16   94,005,364      14,841,793     
Nov-16   123,774,792     7,903,600      41,489,883 
Dec-16   93,355,037      12,449,604     69,117,105 
Jan-17   47,869,982      13,830,712     83,913,764 
Feb-17   77,109,905      10,361,555     68,176,643
```

The goal is to create a formula that, when I drag it down, correctly calculates the average of the last 12 values for a given company.

So for example i would have, say in table "B2:C5":

```
Company1     76,856,345 
Company2     11,120,859 
Company3     65,674,349
```

And, if a new Company4 is added to the list, then I just have to drag it down the formula, to calculate the average of the last 12 months for Company4.

Until now, I have came up with this formula:

```
=AVERAGE(LOOKUP(LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(G:G),ROW(G:G)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MIN(12,COUNT(G:G))))),ROW(G:G),G:G ))
```

This formula correctly calculates the average of a given column, considering only the last 12 values. The last step would be to come up with a formula that includes all the columns and then calculates the average for the given company.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a named range to define your data in columns G:I. When a company is added, just modify the named range's specs. I used the name *Target*. Of course, you can replace it with $G:$I if you feel so inclined but I would rather recommend reducing the number of rows in the range, which is easier to manage when it is named.
Use the formula below to extract the company names from the first row of Target into the first column of your averages table. This is to ensure that the names are spelled identically in both locations.

```
=INDEX(Target,1,ROW()-2)
```

The number 2 indicates the number of rows above the row containing the formula. it is copied here from cell M3. There, ROW()-2 creates the number 1, counting sequentially as the formula is copied down.
Now I have the formula below in my cell N3 and copied down.

```
=SUM(INDEX(Target,0,MATCH($M3,INDEX(Target,1,0),0)))
```

The formula simply sums up the columns G, H, and I in 3 consecutive rows.
In the final step I inserted the range definition established above, meaning excluding the SUM() function, into your existing formula.

```
=AVERAGE(LOOKUP(LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX(Target,0,MATCH($M3,INDEX(Target,1,0),0))),ROW(INDEX(Target,0,MATCH($M3,INDEX(Target,1,0),0)))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MIN(12,COUNT(INDEX(Target,0,MATCH($M3,INDEX(Target,1,0),0))))))),ROW(INDEX(Target,0,MATCH($M3,INDEX(Target,1,0),0))),INDEX(Target,0,MATCH($M3,INDEX(Target,1,0),0))))
```

Comment: As I wrote the formula would be in the table B2:C5, precisely in rows from C2 to how many the companies are.